# How to load content with PHP $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and href

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hello everyone I need some help with this:

I´m a total noob in php and javascript and I´m facing a little problem here , I´m working with a website that displays a list on the left side and then when I do a click on an element it shows a subelement then when I do a click on the subelement it displays a table that contains info stored in a mysql database, it works flawlessly but the data shown sometimes displays like 5000 rows so it's annoying to be scrolling all the way down 5000 rows, so I decided to paginate the results to be able to just show like 100 elements per page.

Now when I click on the link to show the next 100 rows it takes me to another page and my menu on the left disappears!

I´m using something like this to navigate through the results:

```
$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $pn - 1;    
$sub2 = $pn - 2;    
$add1 = $pn + 1;    
$add2 = $pn + 2;

if ($pn == 1) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';

} 
else if ($pn == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';

}
 else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub2 . '">' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add2 . '">' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';

} 
else if ($pn > 1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $sub1 . '">' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $pn . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?pn=' . $add1 . '">' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}
```

My guess is that because the next and back links are an `<a href>` tags it loads a new page showing the next 100 rows.

How can I prevent that??

I tried to use a jquery adding a preventDefault(); to those `<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` tags, it worked but now nothing happend on those links xD.

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you handle the links on the left side? Are they a part of your page here? What you could do is separate them. Either use frame or AJAX. So when you click on those links, you only return the table in some cases and only change the table but not the links on the left.

Comment: yep , the links are in the same page that's why when I do click on the next link it changes the page and the links dissapear, mmm so do I have to use AJAX and jquery ???

Comment: Yeah. Seems like your paging link will only load the table excluding the links. You could include your link status like what page you're in so you know which to show again in the next page load. Then, include links in all pages if you don't want to use. `preventDefault()` will disable the default action of the element which will ignore the click on them.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this example helps you. Its not refreshing the url. So your menu link be opened

you can create pagination link like this

```
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);  

//create pagination
$pagination = '';
if($pages > 1)
{
    $pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';
    for($i = 1; $i<$pages; $i++)
    {
        $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
    }
    $pagination .= '</ul>';
}

?>
```

and here is script for pagination

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

    $(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

        var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
        var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need

        $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

        //post page number and load returned data into result element
        //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php", {'page': (page_num-1)}, function(){

        });

        $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element

        return false; //prevent going to herf link
    });
});
```

and here fetching Pages

```
<?php
include("config.inc.php"); //include config file

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//validate page number is really numaric
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range.
$results = mysqli_query($connecDB,"SELECT id,name,message FROM paginate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

//output results from database
echo '<ul class="page_result">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{
    echo '<li id="item_'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["id"].' <span class="page_name">'.$row["name"].'</span><span class="page_message">'.$row["message"].'</span></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks mate , I've used that before but I still can´t figure how to get thinks working , let's say for example, I have 3 list links:

list a

list b

list c

Let´s pretend that I do a click on the list a, and then it shows the products , but when I do a click on the list b link, the same list a products appears.

Do I have to make a query for every single list item ?